# I need to convert a fixed-width file to 'comma-delimited' in Unix

Tags: unix

I need to convert a fixed-width file to comma-delimited in Unix.

```
k12582927001611USNA
k12582990001497INAS
k12583053001161LNEU
```

Required output:

```
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! This is not a code writing service. We expect that you show some effort of your own. We like to help you, if you got stuck.

Comment: @VMai The question was fine. I ran into the same type of thing. This question with the answers saved me. +1

Comment: Same here, this is a very on point question that generated two very useful answers.

Comment: The listed sample input does not correspond to [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052317/i-need-to-convert-a-fixed-width-file-to-comma-delimited-in-unix/25052503#comment39007739_25052443) *"I am trying to read the space too."*

Comment: It is ill-defined. The requirements aren't even stated. And why is the required output not standard [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)? - the strings are not quoted. An oversight? Due to general sloppiness? For example, the indicated spaces would beg for the strings to be quoted. What if the input contains commas?

Comment: BTW, the *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* site is happy to accept work orders. There will be solutions in many different scripting languages, no questions asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk` and `substr()`:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{ print substr($0, 1, 1), substr($0, 2, 10), substr($0, 12, 4), substr($0, 16, 2), substr($0, 18, 2) }' file
```

Output:

```
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

Comment: I think the code is not reading the space in the fixed width. I am trying to read the space too. For example if the fixed widthe file has : k12582990001497IN  AS ABC and the output should be k,1258299000,1497,IN, ,AS, ,ABC

Comment: @user3894382 You should update your post with your actual input and intended output.

Comment: This code snippet is working perfectly. thanks for the timely help.

Comment: @konsolebox That's a horrible, possibly unlawful practice. Always clean your data for sample data before posting to SOF.

Comment: @DavidBetz That is a very common thing in every question that is posted, and should already be implied. Tell that to the OP instead if you are worried. There's no need to remind people about obvious stuff again and again. Also, I think you should have noticed, but the posted sample data means almost nothing.

Answer (score 21):

Like this with GNU awk:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 10 4 2 2" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
```

`OFS` is the Output Field Separator and I set it to a comma. The `FIELDWIDTHS` variable does all the magic for you.

Or you can do it in [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) like this:

```
perl -ne 'm/(.)(.{10})(....)(..)(..)/; printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5' file
```

Or, in [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) like this:

```
sed -E 's/(.)(.{10})(....)(..)(..)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5/' file
```

Comment: Note, FIELDWIDTHS only works with GNU awk (gawk), not the default `awk` that typically comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: @wisbucky that is true, you have no idea how much this helped me, awk wasnt working

Comment: @wisbucky : true. Solutions involving GNU awk should use in their answers "gawk" instead of "awk" to really show this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pipe the file through:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,1)","substr($0,2,10)","substr($0,12,4)","substr($0,16,2)","substr($0,18,2)}'
```

As per the following test run:

```
pax> echo 'k12582927001611USNA
k12582990001497INAS
k12583053001161LNEU' | awk '
{
    print substr($0,1,1)","substr($0,2,10)","substr($0,12,4)","
        substr($0,16,2)","substr($0,18,2)
}'

k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```