# Comparison between two tab separated files in unix using awk

Tags: shell, unix

I've written this code on unix but I am facing the problem as mentioned below.

> My Code is:

```
paste 1.txt   2.txt|
awk ' { FS = "\t " } ; NR == 1 { n = NF/2 }
              {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                 if($i!=$(i+n))
                   {c = c s i; s = "," }
               if(c)
                 {print "Line No. " NR-1 " COLUMN NO " c;
                  c = "" ; s = "" } } '
```

> Expected Output:

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 2,3
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 2,3,4,5
Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

> Output that is getting generated:

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 2,3
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 2,3,4,5
Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
```

Below specified file is space separated. To understand it better I have formatted it this way.

> File1:

```
ID_ID   First_name  Last_name Address                      Contact_Number
ID1     John        Rock      32, Park Lake, California    2222200000
ID2     Tommy       Hill      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge  3333300000
ID3     Leonardo    Test      Half-Way Pond, Georgetown    4444400000
ID8     Rhyan       Bigsh     6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 5555500000
ID50    Steve       Goldberg  6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 6666600000
ID60    Steve       Goldberg                               6666600000
```

> File2:

```
ID_ID   First_name  Last_name   Address                      Contact_Number
ID1     John        Rock        32, Park Lake, California    2222200000
ID2     Tommy1      Hill1       5322 Otter Lane Middleberge  3333300000
ID3     Leonardo    Test        Half-Way Pond, Georgetown    4444400000
ID80    Sylvester   Stallone                                 5555500000
ID50    Steve       Goldberg    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 6666600000
ID60    Mark        Waugh       St. Petersburg               7777700000
ID70    John        Smith                                    8888800000
```

Comment: There are some double tabs in few places. In File1, ID60 in between Goldberg and 6666600000. In FIle2, ID80 in between Stallone and 5555500000, ID70 in between Smith and  8888800000

Comment: What is the criteria to print the output and 2nd line of file1 is blank, is it a copy/paste issue or the requirement.

Comment: It was the copy/paste issue.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is until there are equal number of lines it's working fine but in my case I have an extra line in File2, it is generating wrong output only for that line only. It is ignoring that double tab.

Comment: You could pass it through `sed` first to replace `<TAB><TAB>` with `<TAB>space<TAB>`, or you could use `awk`'s FIELDWIDTHS feature... http://stackoverflow.com/a/25052503/2836621