# How Do I add Multiple characters using SED?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have files with dates and times formatted as such and about 6 million lines of them

`20211231233710;20211231233713;SomeHEXID;SomeIDNumber;Whatever;0;SomethingElse`

How can I make it so that the dates are formatted in this way?

`2021-12-05 18:05:03;2021-12-05 18:05:04;SomeHEXID;SomeIDNumber;Whatever;0;SomethingElse`

Each line starts in this way.
I have tried something like
`sed -e 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\);\(.*\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6;\7/'     -e 's/\(.*\);\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1;\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:\7/'`
and
`sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(;?)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6\7/g'`
but both of these methods change the text past the first 2 fields.
TIA

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052317/need-to-convert-fixed-width-file-to-comma-delimited-in-unix/25052503

Comment: ``cat test.txt | sed 's/^\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(.*\)$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6\7/' | sed 's/^\(....................\)\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(.*\)$/\1\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:\7\8/``?

Comment: @Cyrus the duplicate reference is certainly helpful but it doesn't deal with multiple fields no?

Comment: @Cyrus, the dupe target does not specify a tool, but all of the answers use `awk`, whereas this question explicitly asks for a `sed` solution.  It may be that the OP would be satisfied either way, but as the question is presently expressed, it is not a dupe of the given target.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, I agree with you, I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to approach the problem with `sed`, but all of the best ones will involve using `s` commands with capturing groups in the pattern and back references in the replacement.  However, any solution based on that tool will need to work around the problem that there are too many separate fields (12) in each line of data to associate all of them with separate back references in a single `s` command.  One fairly simple way to accommodate that would be to split it across two `s` commands, one for the first date code and one for the second.  For example:

```
sed -e 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\);\(.*\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6;\7/' \
    -e 's/\(.*\);\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1;\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:\7/' \
    < input > output
```

The first `sed` expression matches matches each of the first 14 characters with its own `.` wildcard, capturing them in separate groups as specified by the escaped parentheses `\(` ... `\)`, and captures all of the second date code with one additional capturing group matching the tail of the line.  It then replaces everything matched (that is, the whole line) with an intermediate form in which the first date code is formatted but the second is not, something like so:

```
2021-12-05 18:05:03;20211205180504
```

In the replacement part of that `s` command, the `\1` represents the data captured by the first group, the `\2` represents that captured by the second group, *etc*..

The second `sed` expression is similar, but it handles the second time code, producing the wanted overall formatting as the end result.

Comment: `sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(;?)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6\7/g'` should also work no?

Comment: It would appear so, @Fravadona.  I have slightly modified the wording of this answer in light of that alternative.  I like it, but I'll leave my version in this answer to afford the OP a choice between the two.

Comment: This solution makes the most sense to me, but i have other data after the dates, so the entire first line looks like 
`20211231233710;20211231233713;SomeHEXID;SomeIDNumber;Whatever;0;SomethingElse` and both solutions break the rest of the lines to looks like
`2021-12-31 23:37:10;20211231233713;SomeHEXID;SomeIDNumber;Whatever;0;So-me-th in:gE:lse`

Comment: Not cool, @LeoP.  We very much frown on changing questions after you already have answers, especially in ways that invalidate any of the answers.  I'm done here.

Comment: Hey @JohnBollinger, relatively new here and looking for help. I should've included the rest of the line, didn't think it would be relevant. Thanks for your help.